# Удаление записи из listview через CursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, cursoradaper

Здравствуйте, в фрагменте создал кастомный listview, в котором находится некоторая текстовая информация и image для удаления записи из базы.

в активности провожу чтение базы.

```
cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT liked_id as _id, liked_presentation_id FROM liked", null);
LikedListCursorAdapter likedListCursorAdapter = new LikedListCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
lvItems.setAdapter(likedListCursorAdapter);
```

// в классе CursorAdapter создаю клик событие для imageView на удаление строки из БД.

```
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {


   idSpeaker = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));


    imageViewStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.w("id",String.valueOf(idSpeaker));
            mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

            mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();


            mSqLiteDatabase.delete(mDatabaseHelper.TABLE_LIKED,
                    "liked_id = ?",
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(idSpeaker)});
            cursor.requery();

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при клике по image всегда удаляется последний элемент в listview. Как сделать, чтобы позиция курсора была равна позиции выбранного image в listview?

Comment: получайте ID текущей записи методом [`getItemId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#getItemId(int))